# What does this expression calculate

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Suppose **X** and **Y** are two positive integers and **Y** is a power of two. Then what does this expression calculate?

**(X+Y-1) & ~(Y-1)**

I found this expression appearing in certain c/c++ implementation of Memory Pool (**X** represents the object size in bytes and **Y** represents the alignment in bytes, the expression returns the block size in bytes fit for use in the Memory Pool).

Comment: bitfiddling, using binary operators, and and not is the key.

Comment: Why not choose a specific language. Relevant advice is different for C and C++.

Comment: It rounds x up to a multiple of y.

Comment: It calculates one less than the sum of X + Y, bitwise and-ed with the bitwise complement of one less than Y.

Comment: a power of 2 -1 is all bits to the right of the 'power of 2' bit being set to 1s. with all the bits, from the 'power of 2' bit to the left being 0.  the '~' operator then flips all the bits.  However, your question already contains the answer:  "it contains the needed block size"  You should know what a power of 2 is (a single 1 bit), you should know what '~' does. you should know what '&' does. so just what is the question?

Comment: Come on !  If there are 7 answers for this question, this definitively shows that it was an interesting question.  Doesn't the OP deserve better than a -1 ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ There are better and useful answers on this thread. I will rather ignore your "opinion".

Comment: @amitkriit Well, I'll leave my close and downvote though. We seem to disagree, and that's just fine.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ No issues, I was not born to impress you, hence I can live with your "close" and "downvote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume that X and Y are unsigned integers.

Let's have a look at the right part:

- If Y is a power of 2, it is represented in binary by one bit to 1 and all the others to 0.  Example 8 will be binary  00..01000.
- If you substract 1 the highest bit will be 0 and all the bits to its right will become 1.  Example 8-1= 7 and in binary 00..00111
- If you ~ negate this number you will make sure that all highest bit (including the original one will turn to 1 and the lovest to 0.  Example:  ~7 will be 11..11000
- Now if you do a binary AND (&) with any number, you will set to 0 all the lower bits, in our example, the 3 lower bits.  THe resulting number is hence a **multiple of Y**.

Let's look at the left side:

- We've already analysed Y-1.  In our example we had 7, that is 00..00111
- If you add this to any number, you make sure that the result is **greater than or equal to Y**.  Example with 5: 5+7=12 so 00..01100 and example with 10:  10+7=17  so 00..10001
- If you then perform the AND, you'll erase the lower bits. so in our example with 5, we come to 00..01000 = 8 and in our example with 10 we get 00..10000 16.

Conclusion, it's the **smallest multiple of Y wich is greater or equal to X**.

Answer (score 2):

`&~(Y-1)` where `Y` is a power of 2, zeroes the last *n* bits, where `Y` = 2<sup>*n*</sup>: `Y-1` produces *n*  1-bits, inverting that via ~ gives you a mask with *n* zeroes at the end, anding via bit-level `&` zeroes the bits where the mask is zero.

Effectively that produces a number that is some multiple of `Y`'s power of 2.

It can maximally have the effect of subtracting `Y-1` from the number, so add that first, giving `(X+Y-1) & ~(Y-1)`. This is a number that's not less than `X`, and is a multiple of `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

It gives you the next `Y`-aligned address of current address `X`.

Say, your current address `X` is `0x10000`, and your alignment is `0x100`, it will give you `0x10000`. But if your current address `X` is `0x10001`, you will get "next" aligned address of `0x10100`.

This is useful in the scenario that you want your new object always to be aligned to blocks in memory, but not leaving any block unused. So you want to know what is the next available block-aligned address.

Comment: As the OP explained this is about allocation chunk sizes, not about addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try some input and observe what happens?

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned compute(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    return (x + y - 1) & ~(y - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "(x + y - 1) & ~(y - 1)" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 9; ++x)
    {
        std::cout << "x=" << x << ", y=2 -> " << compute(x, 2) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(x + y - 1) & ~(y - 1)" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 9; ++x)
    {
        std::cout << "(x=" << x << ", y=2) -> " << compute(x, 2) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/623d4a2d465e8c82)

**Output:**
First set uses `x` in [0, 8] and `y` is constant `2`. Second set uses `x` in [0, 8] and `y` is constant `4`.

```
(x + y - 1) & ~(y - 1)
x=0, y=2 -> 0
x=1, y=2 -> 2
x=2, y=2 -> 2
x=3, y=2 -> 4
x=4, y=2 -> 4
x=5, y=2 -> 6
x=6, y=2 -> 6
x=7, y=2 -> 8
x=8, y=2 -> 8
----
(x + y - 1) & ~(y - 1)
(x=0, y=2) -> 0
(x=1, y=2) -> 2
(x=2, y=2) -> 2
(x=3, y=2) -> 4
(x=4, y=2) -> 4
(x=5, y=2) -> 6
(x=6, y=2) -> 6
(x=7, y=2) -> 8
(x=8, y=2) -> 8
```

It's easy to see the output (i.e., result right of `->`) is always a multiple of `y` such that the output is greater than or equal to `x`.

Comment: I was more interested in "How" than "What".

Comment: @amitkriit Okay, although that wasn't obvious since your question explicitly asked "**What** does this expression calculate"? rather than "How does this calculation work"?

Comment: What you have provided is Empirical Evidence and doesn't establish the "What" part. That is why I said that I am more interested in "How".

Comment: @amitkriit Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down, piece by piece.

```
(X+Y-1) & ~(Y-1)
```

Let's suppose that X = 11 and Y = 16 in accordance with your rules and that the integers are 8 bits.

```
(11+16-1) & ~(16-1)
```

Do the Addition and Subtraction

```
(26) & ~(15)
```

Translate this into binary

```
(0001 1010) & ~(0000 1111)
```

~ means not or to invert the zeros and ones

```
(0001 1010) & (1111 0000)
```

& means only to take the bits that are both ones

```
0001 0000
```

convert back to decimal

```
16
```

other examples

```
X = 78, Y = 32 results in 96
X = 25, Y = 64 results in 64
X = 47, Y = 16 results in 48
```

So, it would seem to me that the purpose of this is to find lowest multiple of Y that is equal to or greater than X. This could be used for finding the start/end address of a block of memory, or it could be used for positioning items on the screen, or any number of other possible answers as well. But without context and possibly even a full code example. There's no guarantee.

Comment: ITYM "lowest multiple".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks! A lot of people have provided similar answers in the time I was composing this. I'm impressed. There wasn't a single answer when I started.

Answer (score 0):

It seems provides a specified alignment of a value for example of a memory address (for example when you want to get the next aligned address).

For example if you want that a memory address would be aligned at the paragraph bound you can write

```
( address + 16 - 1 ) & ~( 16 - 1 )
```

or

```
( address + 15 ) & ~15
```

or

```
( address + 15 ) & ~0xf
```

In this case all bits before 16 will be zeroed.

This part of expression

```
( address + alignment - )
```

is used for rounding.

and this part of expression

```
~( alignment - 1 )
```

is used to build a mask thet zeroes low bits.

Comment: As the OP explained this is about allocation chunk sizes, not about addresses.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In fact it is the same.

Comment: No, an address is not a size. The calculations are the same. The purpose is very different. For the address calculation one can use `std::align` in C++. For the size, one has to at least add some shenaginans to the mix.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is the same because you need to get aligned value.

Comment: No, an address is not the same as a size. An address is usually a pointer. A size is usually an integer. Apart from the type system interference and the different standard library support, the concepts and usage are different.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did not say that an addres is the same as a size. I say that this allows to get aligned value. How and where you will use it it is unimportant. Yu can use it to get the next aligned address or to calculate a chunk of memory. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

(X+Y-1) & ~(Y-1)

```
x = 7 = 0b0111
y = 4 = 0b0100

x+y-1 = 0b1010
y-1 = 3 = 0b0011
~(y-1) = 0b1100

(x+y-1) & ~(y-1) = 0b1000 = 8
```

--

```
x = 12 = 0b1100
y = 2 = 0b0010
x+y-1 = 13 = 0b1101

y-1 = 1 = 0b0001
~(y-1) = 0b1110

(x+y-1) & ~(y-1) = 0b1100 = 12
```

(x+y-1) & ~(y-1) is the smallest multiple of y greater than or equal to x